# No function `emmeans_test` when using package "emmeans"

Tags: r, anova, emmeans, posthoc

I'm doing a three-way ANOVA and I want to do a post-hoc analysis on it.

To make a comparison by groups, I saw that function `emmeans_test` from the package **emmeans** was the best option. But when I run my code, **R** doesn't find `emmeans_test`. I don't understand why. I have installed **emmeans** and done `library(emmeans)` already.

```
library(emmeans)

donnees_tot_g_J4 %>%
  group_by(quality, temperature) %>%
  emmeans_test(growth_rate ~ quantity, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

Error in emmeans_test(., growth_rate ~ quantity, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"):
  could not find function "emmeans_test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `emmeans_test` is not from **emmeans** but from **rstatix**. So you need:

```
if (!require(rstatix)) install.packages("rstatix")
library(rstatix)
```

> Thank you, it was that ! Sorry for the dumb question.

Don't worry. The name is indeed misleading. And in fact, neither package depends on or imports the other. **rstatix** only suggests that it could enhance **emmeans**.

---

Thanks for the useful feedback from [dipetkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9566484).

> Actually, **rstatix** calls **emmeans** to do the actual analysis; it's not enhancing anything. It can't deal for example with a model that omits the three-way interactions.

Sorry for the confusion. My statement is based on what I saw from the CRAN page for **rstatix**. Surprisingly, **emmeans** is in neither "depends" nor "imports"; only in "suggests". Don't know how that `emmeans_test` would work if the package does not import **emmeans** in the first place.

> I strongly suggest to the OP to learn how to do their analysis with `lm()` followed by `emmeans()`, as they'll have lots more flexibility (and confidence in the results).

Thanks. I update my answer to pass this suggestion to OP, as well as future readers.

Comment: Actually, `rstatix` calls `emmeans` to do the actual analysis; it's not enhancing anything. It can't deal for example with a model that omits the three-way interactions. I strongly suggest to the OP to learn how to do their analysis with `lm()` followed by `emmeans()` as they'll have lots more flexibility (and confidence in the results).